# Android studio, I cant install HAXM with AMD

Tags: android-studio, emulation, amd-processor, haxm

I tried to install the emulator in android studio and when I want to install HAXM, I can't.
I have tried all the different question about the topic, that I can find, here on StackOverflow, but it still doesn't work.

The error that appears:

> The computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x).

[image]

My computer is an AMD, but does it have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old issue that they have apparently since [fixed](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html):

> Support for AMD® processors and Microsoft Hyper-V hypervisor are two long-standing user requests from the Android developer community that we are happy to address with this Android Emulator update.

Make sure you're using the most up-to-date version of Android Emulator by using the SDK Manager in Android Studio